# Downloading a package with R 3.6 that requires hashmap as a dependency

Tags: r, hashmap

I am trying to download nflscrapR with R 3.6 and it requires hashmap as a dependency. When downloading the package, I get the following message:

ERROR: dependency 'hashmap' is not available for package 'nflscrapR'

Are there any ways to get around this? I tried looking up hashmap on CRAN and the webpage seems to have been taken down.

Comment: How are you downloading this? devtools? And have you tried to install hashmap first?

Comment: The `hashmap` package has been removed from CRAN (yesterday, no less). Unfortunately, the [original package](https://github.com/nathan-russell/hashmap) has not shown recent updates, and according to CRAN the maintainer is unresponsive. You can always try `devtools::install_github("nathan-russell/hashmap")` (I have not tried), perhaps that will install *that* package so that you can move on to `nflscrapR`.

Comment: I have tried downloading it separately but that did not seem to work either. I'll try downloading it from github

Answer (score 0):

I know that it won't help you since you're trying to resolve dependency issue, but hashmap datastructure can be found in "datastructures" library.